# Why don't new versions of IE and Edge support CSS filter effects?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser, microsoft-edge, browser-support

I've been enjoying using these effects and I don't mind them gracefully degrading in older browsers, but [Internet Explorer 11 and Edge 12](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) still don't support them.

This isn't the first time Microsoft avoids adopting specifications that are widely in use everywhere else.

I understand Edge was a big project and the IE browser was also re-worked from the ground up in IE8/9, but it sometimes almost *seems* like IE/Edge deliberately makes things difficult for designers and developers in the lack of continuity between it and what other browsers like Firefox, Chrome and Safari are adopting.

Are there reasons for this that I'm failing to recognize?

Comment: Latest MS browser should be partially supporting them. If you want a cross browser solution, svg filters have been implemented since IE9. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Answer (score 0):

CSS Filter effects are supported as per https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/css/filter-effects/

I have seen them on my own website https://trajano.net/ except for one scenario that is [Do CSS Filter Effects work when position:absolute in Edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471737/do-css-filter-effects-work-when-positionabsolute-in-edge)